# How to deploy a C# (ClickOnce?) project that is a wrapper on a command line .exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

I have a C# project which is basically a GUI used to call other executable(s) with command line arguments. (The command line exe was actually built with cygwin and uses the cugwin DLL).

So the directory structure that needs to exist once the app is deployed (via setup.exe or whatever) is this:

```
install dir --->   MyApp.exe
                   MyApp.config
                   (dir) bin   ---> cmd1.exe
                                    cmd2.exe
                                    cygwin.dll
```

Now this ought to be simple, but whatever I try, I cannot get the bin directory and its contents to be copied when I install on a second machine with setup.exe. I tried:
  - adding them as resources
  - setting "Build Action" to Content
  - setting "Copy To Output Directory" to Always

But the bin directory was never copied across when I did this. I have tried searching here and elsewhere but I am still at a loss.

Should this be a "ClickOnce" project? (what does this even mean - are there also ClickTwice and ClickUntilYouCanClickNoMore projects - ok, excuse me ...)

Also do I get setup.exe to put this app somewhere sane like C://Program Files/MyOrg/Myapp  - instead of being buried somewhere in the user's profile?

(Using VS 2019.)

Comment: Is it possible that "bin" is a reserved folder and hence it is not getting copied? Did you try some other "foldername"? ClickOnce allows you to copy your installed directory wherever a user prefers. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019

Comment: tyhanks for swift response. Maybe. I will check. Do I need to include "bin" and all its files, or the files only? If I include a certain file, will it be copied automatically into the same path, creating the structure? how does this work?

Comment: When you mark a file to copy, it's folder structure should be copied too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot add an image in a comment, I am adding them here.  Here is how my folder structure looks like.

I have a .p12 file and have marked it as "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always"

[image]

When the project is built, the file gets copied inside bin folder with the file's folder structure which includes "keystore" folder as well.

[image]

As a curiosity, I just tried out renaming my folder "keystore" to "bin" (I had to delete existing bin folder), and then added the .p12 file to it.  The project compiled, generated new exe file and also copied .p12 file with appropriate folder structure.  I am not sure what means to building and generating a Setup.exe though. You can try and let us know if it worked for you.

[image]

Comment: thank you - I will try this tomorrow and get back to you. looks helpful.

Comment: ok, with a bit of experimenting, I got this going. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To package the specified file into ClickOnce, you just need to add it to `Application Files...`.

The following is the folder structure.

[image]

And then confirm it has been added into `Application Files...`.

[image]

Last step, publish it. And you can access the image like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/img/a.jpg");
}
```

As to `put this app somewhere sane`, I am afraid the answer is no.

ClickOnce's installation path cannot be changed. You can find it at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`.